# Perturbing a matrix to get a specific determinant

Tags: continuity, determinant, inverse

Define the function $h:\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}\times\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $h(A,C)=\det(A+C)-\det(A)$

My question is the following: Does there exist a continuous function $C:\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}\times[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ such that

1. $h(A,C(A,t))=t$ for all $A\in[0,1]^{n\times n}$ and $t\in[0,1]$
2. $C(A,0)=0$ for all $A\in[0,1]^{n\times n}$

The the domain of $C$ is $n^2+1$ dimensional with compact domain while there are only two scalar constraints on $C$. This makes it seem like the answer to my question is yes, but I don't know how to prove it.

This is what I have tried:

If $A$ is invertible, you can take $C(A,t)=\frac{At}{\det(A)}$ but this doesn't work if $\det(A)=0$ and is not continuous with respect to $A$.

In the case $n=1$, one can take $C(A,t)=t$.

In the nD case, I tried the substitution $t=u^n$ and $C(A,t)=B(A)u$. Then I get $$(1-\det(B(A)))u^{n-1}+\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}p_i(A,B(A))u^i=0$$ where every term of $p_i(A,B(A))$ has degree $i$ in the entries of $B(A)$ and degree $n-i$ in the entries of $A$. This means that $h(A,C(A,t))=t$ if $\det(B(A))=1$ and $p_i(A,B(A))=0$ for every $i$, which forms a system of $n$ polynomial equations in $n^2$ variables for each fixed $A$.

Comment: If $A\in\Bbb{R}^n,$ then how did you define det$(A)?$

Comment: Thanks, Nik. I fixed the typo

Comment: In the case that $\det (A) \ne 0$, the solution you proposed ($C(A,t) = At / \det(A)$ ) is not true. Indeed, $\det (A+C) = \det (A\cdot (1 +t/ \det (A)) = \det(A) \cdot (1+ t/ \det(A))^{\color{red}{n}}$. And so, $h(A,C) = \det(A) \left((1+ t/ \det(A))^\color{red}{n} - 1 \right) \ne t$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each $n \geq 2$, such a function $C$ does not exist due to topological reasons.

An observation is the following.

**Lemma**: There does not exist a continuous function $\phi: \mathbb{R}^n \times [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}^n$, such that $\phi(x, 0) = x$, while $\phi(x, t) \in \mathbb{R}^n \backslash \{0\}$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^n, t > 0$.

**Proof**: If such a map $\phi$ exists, consider the map $\psi(x) = \phi(x, \max(1 - |x|, 0))$, This is a continuous map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n \backslash \{0\}$ that is the identity on $S^{n - 1}$. Such a map cannot exist, since the inclusion $S^{n - 1} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is null-homotopic, but the inclusion $S^{n - 1} \to \mathbb{R}^n \backslash \{0\}$ is not. $\square$

Returning to your original problem. For each $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ let $A(x)$ denote the matrix with $x$ in the first row and zero everywhere else. Let $\pi_1(A)$ be the first row of a matrix $A$. If your desired $C$ exists, the the map $\phi(x, t) = \pi_1(A(x) + C(A(x), t))$ satisfies the properties in the lemma, contradiction.